# Get port number of a switch a pc is connected to

Tags: networking, command-prompt, snmp, switching

I would like to know what are the steps to get the exact port number of the switch my pc is connected to. I'm advised SNMP can solve that but i have so little background about networking. If it really can supply me the port number then how do you do it? If possible, I would like to ask the detailed steps like what do you need to download beforehand etc. And if there are any other simpler ways to get port numbers through the command prompt only, any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would depend on what kind of switch you have... If it provides SNMP information, that might be a useful and easy way. But if you have an unmanaged switch, you just might need to trace the cable, which should work in any case - or read the label on the cable (you do label things, right?).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should correlate data from different MIB tables:

1. Management MIB2 Interfaces
2. Ethernet MIB dot3Stats
3. Management MIB2 dot1dBridge